# Bloqueando qualquer outro aplicativo via Service

Tags: java, android

Fala galera, estou criando um aplicativo de negócios e preciso bloquear qualquer outro aplicativo que o usuário tente abrir.
Estou criando um serviço para isso, mas ele não está funcionando.

Quando executado, ele não ve as outras aplicações quando abertas pelo usuário.

Eu li alguns outros posts aqui, mas eu não consegui resolver.

Abaixo está o meu serviço.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        startService(new Intent(this, clsServico.class));
    }
```

minha classe:

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class clsServico extends Service {

    private static final long INTERVAL = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2); // em segundos
    private static final String TAG = clsServico.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String APS_BG = "APS_BG";

    private Thread t = null;
    private Context ctx = null;
    private boolean running = false;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        running =false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        running = true;
        ctx = this;

        // checa periodicamente se tem algum outro app na tela
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    //checkAPS();

                    try {
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                            listTasks();
                        else
                            listTasks_SDK21();

                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }while(running);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        t.start();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void listTasks() throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = mgr.getAppTasks();
            String packagename;
            String label;
            for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasks) {
                packagename = task.getTaskInfo().baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
                label = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
                //Log.i(TAG, packagename + ":" + label);
            }
        }
    }

    public void listTasks_SDK21() throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> tasks = mgr.getRecentTasks(20, 0);
        String packagename;
        String label;
        for(ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo task: tasks){
            packagename = task.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
            label = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
            Log.i(TAG,packagename + ":" + label);
        }
    }

    private void checkAPS() {
        /*
        if(apenasAPSAtivado(ctx)) {
            if(isInBackground()) {
                restoreApp(); // tras p frente
            }
        }
        */

        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


        List<ResolveInfo> appList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
        List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
        for(int i=0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
            ApplicationInfo a = p.applicationInfo;
            // skip system apps if they shall not be included
            if((a.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
                continue;
            }
            //Log.i("packageName","" + p.packageName);
        }

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo run = RunningTask.get(0);
        Log.i("topActivity", run.topActivity.getClassName());




        Intent ints = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        ints.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> intentlist = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(ints, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> processes = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        String pName = "";

        if (processes != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) {
                String packageName = processes.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName();
                ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo temp = processes.get(i);
                try
                {
                    pName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                }
                catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Log.i("RunningTaskInfo",pName + " : " + temp.id);
                /*
                if (savedapp.equals(pName)) {
                    // finish(pm.);
                    int code = intentlist.get(i).activityInfo.hashCode();
                    finishActivity(code);

                    mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
                    mActivityManager.restartPackage(packageName);
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(temp.id);
                    finishActivity(temp.id);
                }
                */

            }

        }


        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> rt = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1000);
        for(int i = 0; i < rt.size(); i++){
            ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = rt.get(i);
            String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
            //Log.i("rt", activityOnTop);
        }
        //ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = rt.get(0);
        //String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
        //Log.i("activityOnTop", activityOnTop);


        //ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++)
        {
            ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo p = pids.get(i);
            if(!p.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("nog.aps3")){
                android.os.Process.killProcess(p.pid);
                try {
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(p.pid);
                    android.os.Process.sendSignal(p.pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
                    mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(p.processName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Log.i("try", e.toString());
                }
            }

            //Log.i("info.processName", p.processName);
            //isInBackground();
        }

    }

    private boolean isInBackground() {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        //Log.i("getPackageName", ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +" =? "+ componentInfo.getPackageName());

        return (!ctx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName().equals(componentInfo.getPackageName()));
    }

    private void restoreApp() {
        //restore other class
    }

    public boolean apenasAPSAtivado(final Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sp.getBoolean(APS_BG, false);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso, pls?

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente você não conseguirá impedir que outros aplicativos rodem.

Isso se dá pelo fato de cada APP rodar em uma JVM separada, ou seja, cada um roda na sua "caixinha" e nenhuma tem acesso ao que a outra está fazendo.

As interações entre as JVM (inclusive com aplicações do sistema) é feita através de intenções, isso significa que cada Aplicação vai decidir como irá tratar essa requisição.

Colocando de um modo geral, o seu processo e tudo que existe nele só poderá ser terminado por duas "entidades": Seu próprio aplicativo ou o próprio sistema Android.

Alguns aplicativos, como os "Limpadores de memória" fazem alguns workaround (normalmente fazendo com que o Sistema tenha que encerrar os aplicativos em segundo plano para garantir a usabilidade do que está em primeiro plano), mas isso não é exatamente garantido.

Se a sua intenção for "capar" o usuário, permitindo que ele utilize o dispositivo apenas para a sua aplicação, você pode experimentar o [Android for Work](https://www.android.com/work/), não cheguei a testá-lo, mas pelo que vi nos dispositivos API 20+ você consegue utilizar duas contas (uma pessoal e uma empresarial) e alguns aplicativos só ficariam disponíveis na conta empresarial (e nenhum outro da pessoal).

Comment: Olá Lucas, sua explicação faz sentido, na verdade foi a primeira coisa que eu disse quando me pediram, mas existem aplicativos que fazem isso sem ter a necessidade de fazer ROOT.... eis a questão! :).. esse é um exemplo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard&hl=pt-br

Comment: Ah... meu cliente mostrou um que faz isso, sem root tb!

Comment: Pra esse que você me mostrou não é necessário mesmo, acredito que ele mude a configuração da rede adicionando algum tipo de Proxy, e ele controla o acesso no Proxy, sem interferir nas outras aplicações.